# C++ OpenCV svm train crashes

Tags: c++, opencv

I have two vectors:

```
vector<int> features;
vector<int> labels;
```

And in some point into my program I fill them with some values. (both vectors same size) Then, when I want to train the `svm` I copy the vectors into 2 new `cv::Mat` like this:

```
Mat trainMat(features.size(), 1, CV_32FC1);
Mat labelsMat(labels.size(), 1, CV_32FC1);
for (int i = 0; i < features.size(); i++) {
    trainMat.at<int>(i, 1) = features.at(i);
    labelsMat.at<int>(i, 1) = labels.at(i);
}
```

Then I create the `svm` and it's `params`:

```
cv::SVMParams params;
params.svm_type = cv::SVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = cv::SVM::POLY;
params.gamma = 3;
cv::SVM svm;
```

And finally I train it:

```
svm.train(trainMat, labelsMat, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

But, the program crashes and gives this error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x7484D928 in cvtest.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0017F04.
```

At first, I thought the problem was the size of the data(because I compile it at 32bit). So, I used only 20, even 4 samples just to test it. But, still crashing. What else could result a memory error?

Comment: if you call cv::namedWindow("test"); does the window have some cryptic name?

Comment: I have this: `cv::namedWindow("Display");` Should I close the window before start training?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem. `svm.train()` accepts only `float` type features and not `int`. I just changed `vector<int> features;` to `vector<float> features;` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating trainMat and labelsMat as float matrices with CV_32FC1 but setting the values with `trainMat.at<int>` which is wrong. 
It has to be `trainMat.at<float>`.